# How can I constrain a button to the bottom of the screen and a text view at the same time

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have the following simple app design. A toolbar, textview and button.

[image: Android app layout]

How can I build this layout design such that:

1. When the text is small the button is constrained to the bottom of the screen
2. When the text is longer it does not extend under the button, but rather stretches the height of the scrollview

EDIT: Here's the solution as @MariosP described below.  Constrain the button to both the textview and the bottom of the screen. If you do this however you'll see that the button defaults to averaging the two constraints, so it floats equally between the two vertically which is not what I wanted. The trick is to use `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"` on the button. This tells the layout that you don't want the button to be in the middle of it's vertical constraints but instead wants to be on the far bottom (the bottom edge) of the two constraints. altering that bias number between 0 and 1 will make the button slide along those vertical constraints. If you're getting layouts where buttons are hovering over your other textviews this info will help you out.

Comment: Can you please share your current layout? or anything that you have done

Comment: Plus one for the constraintVertical_bias edit. Was a solution to my issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this behaviour using a ScrollView with a child of ConstraintLayout. Below is the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_light" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**Result with a Small Text:**

[image]

**Result with a Long Text (after scrolling to the bottom):**

[image]